# How do I get a datagrid type control in fsprojects/Fabulous

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#, elmish, elmish-wpf

fsproject/Fabulous does not appear to have a datagrid. That would be a columnated ListView with non-scrolling header and footer rows (not grouping headers). Such a control seems essential for any line of business (LOB) application. It is also necessary for tablet and desktop size screens that can present a lot of tabulated information clearly.

Am I missing something?

Presently, I am exploring constructing something as perhaps the following, but am still a novice at `Xamarin` and `Fabulous` (`Fabulous-Simple-Elements` actually):

```
grid row of header columns...
grid row of list view of grid row of data columns...
grid row of footer columns...
```

Comment: You tagged elmish-wpf, but it doesn't seem to me like your question is related to Elmish.WPF.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed, I was trying to verify a datagrid exists within Elmish.WPF and became aware the Elm itself doesn't have the notion of a "virtual" datagrid. Presumably one could be readily implemented but it hasn't been.

Comment: Do you know of an any example of such a datagrid in any WPF application?

Comment: I believe this is such a grid...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.enablerowvirtualization?view=netframework-4.8